# XCUITest failed for URL: "gplus://" - error:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Hi when I am running my tests on xcuitest my tests will stop at the same point and through this error.

`2017-02-28 11:15:16.501 VoucherCodes[60897:11082496] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "gplus://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme gplus"`

and

`Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x116c84998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x116aa6880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

has anyone come into this before? What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: are you added the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your .plist

Comment: I have not - what should it look like in my plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your **Info.plist** and add **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** as shown below

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>gplus</string>
</array>
```